# While I am solve $(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4t$, I don't know why my answer is wrong..

Tags: calculus

$(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4t$

$(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt}= 4t -2ty$

$(4+t^2)dy = 4t dt -2tydt$

$\int (4+t^2)dy = \int( 4t -2ty )dt$

$4y+t^2y = 2t^2 -t^2y+ c$

$y(4+2t^2)= 2t^2 +c $

$y = \frac{2t^2 + c}{4+2t^2}$

This is my answer, but the text book answer is $y = \frac{2t^2 + c}{4+t^2}$

This is text book.... answer and solution

[image]

I don't know why my answer is wrong.

so... to solve this kind of question... can't I solve like what I did ? ( multiply both side with dt)

Comment: $y$ depends on $t$, so you can't say $$\int 2ty dt = t^2y + C$$

Comment: Write $$y' +\frac{2t}{4+t^2}y=\frac{4t}{4+t^2}$$ after line three.

Comment: What is different between this problem and normal dx/dy problem..? I thought normal dx/dy problems also y is depends on x...

Comment: $\int 2xydx = x^2y + C $ is this also wrong? cuase y depends on x

Answer (score 2):

The basic error was integrating **before** the variables were separated.

\begin{eqnarray}
(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty &=& 4t\\
(4+t^2)\,dy+2ty\,dt&=&4t\,dt\\
(4+t^2)\,dy+(2ty-4t)\,dt&=&0\\
(4+t^2)\,dy+2t(y-2)\,dt\\
\frac{1}{y-2}\,dy+\frac{2t}{4+t^2}\,dt&=&=0\\
\ln\vert y-2\vert+\ln\vert 4+t^2\vert&=&\ln\vert c\vert\\
\ln\vert(y-2)(4+t^2)\vert&=&\ln\vert c\vert\\
(y-2)(4+t^2)&=&c\\
y-2&=&\frac{c}{4+t^2}\\
y&=&\frac{c}{4+t^2}+2\\
y&=&\frac{c+8+2t^2}{4+t^2}\\
y&=&\frac{2t^2+C}{4+t^2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is
$$(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4t$$
$$(4+t^2)y' + (4+t^2)'y = 4t$$
$$[(4+t^2)y]' = 4t$$
$$d[(4+t^2)y]= 4tdt$$
$$(4+t^2)y= 2t^2+C$$

Answer (score 0):

your DE is not separable, that is why your answer is wrong from line 4.

If you don't realize that the left hand side is a product rule as it is posted in the solution, maybe you might try to write down the equation as

$$\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{2t}{4+t^2}y = \frac{4t}{4+t^2}$$

and use a standard method to solve linear differential equations.

For solving matters, you are allowed "to multiply" by a differential ($dy,dt...$), but strictly speaking, these expressions are not just variables or numbers that you can manipulate freely algebraically, you need to be careful with what they truly mean and avoid these kind of common mistakes that you just committed.

Comment: what you mean about my DE is not separable..? Also, why some of equations can be solved with my way and.. the other cannot be solved with my way..?

Comment: Roughly speaking, a differential equation is separable if you are able to write it down in the form $f(t)dt = g(y)dy$, in a more colloquial sense, you are able to separate each variable from the other and have just one variable on each side of your equation.  When you are able to do this, you can use your way.

Comment: Oh......  
$\int2xydx=x^2y+C$ might be wrong right ?